# Change the location of toast message for multiple buttons in Android Studio

Tags: java, android

This is a snippet of my code from the main activity file. In this code, I have 4 buttons, and 1 Image Button.

`

```
@Override  
 
public void onClick(View v) {

                if (v.getId() == btn1.getId()) {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Top Left Button Clicked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

//                    toast.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_VERTICAL | Gravity.START, 90,0);
//                    toast.show();`

`} else if (v.getId() == btn2.getId()) {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Top Right Button Clicked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

//                    toast.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_VERTICAL | Gravity.START, 90,0);
//                    toast.show();`

`} else if (v.getId() == btn3.getId()) {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Bottom Left Button Clicked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

//                    toast.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_VERTICAL | Gravity.START, 90,0);

//                    toast.show();`
`} else if (v.getId() == btn4.getId()) {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Bottom Right Button Clicked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

``} else {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Android Button Clicked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

//                    toast.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_VERTICAL | Gravity.START, 90,0);

//                    toast.show();`
`  }
            }
        };`
```

I've set the some lines as comments because if I run the app with those lines of code, the app suddenly stop and doesn't work. If someone could fix the code so that the toast message for each button can be shown at different positions, that would be much appreciated.

I've tried using gravity function, but that did not change the position of the toast message. If anyone could help me and fix the code, that would be helpful. The gravity toast codes are set as commands.

Answer (score 1):

First you need to create an object `toast` and then assign the desired properties to it. (The used command `Toast.makeText(...).show();` is a convenient shortcut for the following lines without the third one, but does not let you access the object to change properties, except for the text). Therefore replace all `Toast.makeText(...).show();` with

```
Toast toast;
toast = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "... Button Clicked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT); 
toast.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_VERTICAL | Gravity.START, 90,0);
toast.show();
```